# Progress indicator on a form submit targeting an iframe to show load progress in a browser other than IE, i.e. not using document.readyState

Tags: jquery, html, forms, iframe, web

I have a forms control on my html page, with a target set to the name of another hidden iframe on the page.

When I do a form.submit via a post call, I wish to show a busy/progress indicator until I receive a response from the post request within the iframe.

I tried using document.getElementById("iframename").readyState in IE and it works like a treat, but how do I handle such a scenario in Chrome/Firefox/Safari etc...?

My understanding is that the readyState is not available in other browsers for the html elements including the iframe, except for IE.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at

http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

Instead of using browser dependant onreadystate,
1) We randomly generate a key to be submitted with the form.
2) In javascript, show progress indicator, run a timer that checks for match of cookie and key, if match, clear timer and hide progress, before submitting.
3) We read the key on the server, append the key to the cookie response.
4) On response, if cookie match, progress indicator will hide.

Ingenious!

Answer (score 1):

SInce you tagged `jQuery` I assume it’s OK to use.

I have had some pretty good results using the `.load()` listener, like this:

```
$('#myframe').load(function() {
    // loaded iframe
});
```

Comment: Tried that, load does get fired, only on initial load.  Will not fire when invoking forms.submit thereafter.

Comment: But it fires when you do a POST and reload the iframe, no?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to add I am returning a application/pdf content type in the header on return, tried returning nothing it works.

Comment: Your answer did help me, but I found a different solution